# Cgi programming with python

Tags: python, bash, cgi

I am trying to execute a python cgi script which is having a bash script that logs into remote servers to get logs. This log is seen in browser.

I am able to run this script from terminal and get expected result. Whereas trying to run this script over a browser. There is no result a blank page shows up. 
After lot of analysis found that When running from browser it runs as apache user who does not have permission to login to remote servers.

I want to make it run as a particular user is that possible ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: What command is the script using to log into the remote servers?

Comment: The bash script runs ssh without password